# Question about Tutte set

Tags: graph-theory

A Tutte set in a graph $G$ is a subset $S$ of vertices of $G$ with $o(G-S) -|S| >0$. Show that in a connected graph of even order that does not have a perfect matching, every vertex in a smallest Tutte Set $S$ has neighbors in at least three odd components of $G-S$.

Conclude that every graph of even order that does not contain an induced subgraph of $K_{1,3}$ has a perfect matching.

I showed if a graph $G$ with even number of vertices and has no perfect matching, then there is a set $S \subseteq V(G)$ such that $o(G-S) \geq |S|+2$, but I don't know how to proceed after that (i.e. every vertex in a smallest Tutte Set $S$ has neighbors in at least three odd components of $G-S$).

Comment: What does the $o$ mean?

Comment: sorry, $o(G-S)$ means odd component of $G-S$